# How to Ignore localhost on Azure application insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I started hosting my first production application recently. I went ahead and activated application insights, which I think have a lot of value. However, I'm getting stats which come from the developer side, for example logs are recording entries from localhost:xxxx. I'm sure there is a way to turn this off. Can anyone give me some pointers please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also filter localhost telemetry using TelemetryProcessor (if you are using the latest (prerelease version of Application Insights Web SDK). Here's an example. Add this class to your project:

```
public class LocalHostTelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor next;
    public LocalHostTelemetryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = item as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry != null && requestTelemetry.Url.Host.Equals("localhost", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.next.Process(item);
        }   
    }
}
```

And then register it in ApplicationInsights.config:

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="LocalhostFilterSample.LocalHostTelemetryFilter, LocalHostFilterSample"/>
</TelemetryProcessors>
```

Comment: This is nicer way because I can send a custom header with Selenium and this code can then ignore my tests. Yea I know, I should have a dedicated test environment.. sure. But at least I am testing.. :D

Comment: A better version of this that deals with all kinds of logging, not only those due to requests, is to inject IHostingEnvironment env into the constructor and check for if(env.IsDevelopment()) return;

Answer (score 9):

1. You can filter out already collected telemetry that you get with F5 in UI because it has property IsDeveloperMode=true
2. You can have web.config transformation that removes Application Insights module from web.debug.config and leaves it only in web.release.config (if you have only auto-collected properties)
3. You can remove instrumentation key from config and set it only for release version in code: TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InsrumentationKey = "MyKey" (if you do not provide iKey in debug you can still see all telemetry in AI hub in VS 2015)
4. You can use different iKeys for debug and release again by setting it in code
5. You can disable ApplicationInsights completely in debug by setting TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true

Comment: I added the following lines of code in my FilterConfig.cs:
`#if !RELEASE               
                TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
            #endif`
Anastasia, Do you think this would work?

Comment: If you have a standard application that defines RELEASE and if you do not create any custom TelemetryConfiguration in code than yes. DisableTelemetry is applicable to each TelemetryConfiguration. Autocollection uses only TelemetryConfiguration.Active. Also I do not know if you track smth before code in FilterConfig is reached (e.g some traces). If yes, than those telemetry would obviously be sent.