# Application Insights - how to exclude localhost

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have added application insights by standard way to my application, it works fine, I collect telemetry data from local website and from working project, published on Azure. But there are many data is sent from localhost, how can I say to not send any data from localhost? Thank you

Comment: Remove the `key` from the local configuration, and add it only to the published application on Azure.  As you are using Azure Web Sites, you can use the portal to override `app.settings` values.

Comment: You can disable ApplicationInsights completely in debug by setting TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true

Comment: @JoeyCai, but it disable ai at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brendan said, you could remove `InstrumentationKey` in ApplicationInsights.config on your localhost and set it only for release version in code: 
`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InsrumentationKey = "MyKey"` .

Also, you could **Disabling telemetry** by setting the following code as this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics) said.

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
```

For more detail about how to ignore localhost on Application Insights, you could refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370209/how-to-ignore-localhost-on-azure-application-insights).